# Mix pattern matching into a chain of maps and filters

Tags: scala

Suppose I want to do something like the following, in which I manipulate a scala list and then perform a match to convert into an option. Is there a way to continue the chain without adding parentheses (for more complicated examples, nesting parentheses could look confusing)?

```
  def foo: Option[Int] = {
    MyUtils.myListOfFoo
      .flatMap(_.barList)
      .filter(_.isGood)
      .toList match {
        case List(bar) => Some(addr)
        case _         => None
      }
      .map(_.getBaz) // would like to do something like this w/o adding parens
      .map(_.numBlah)
  }
```

Comment: I didn't try to replicate this (with real types) but simply dropping the `match` keyword should do it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me unless I'm misunderstanding the suggestion.

Comment: You can think of `match` as a kind of super-low precedence operator, which means you're out of luck here.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate it with the pimp my library pattern:

```
  object MyUtils {

    implicit class ListOpts[A](val l: List[A]) extends AnyVal {
      def myMatch[B](pf: PartialFunction[List[A], Option[B]]): Option[B] =
        pf.applyOrElse(l, (_: List[A]) => None)
      }

    ...
  }
```

Then import it in scope

```
  import MyUtils._
```

Finally, your parensless pipeline is

```
  def foo: Option[Int] = {
    myListOfFoo // imported
      .flatMap(_.barList)
      .filter(_.isGood)
      .toList // Not needed as filter already returns a List
      .myMatch { // resolved implicitly
        case List(bar) => Some(addr)
        case _         => None // Not needed as it's handled by myMatch
      }
      .map(_.getBaz) // would like to do something like this w/o adding parens. Now you can :-)
      .map(_.numBlah)
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

What I mean is this (and I was wrong about merely removing the `match`, you have to use `map`:

```
  def foo: Option[Int] = {
    MyUtils.myListOfFoo
      .flatMap(_.barList)
      .filter(_.isGood)
      .toList map {
        case List(bar) => Some(addr)
        case _         => None
      }
      .map(_.getBaz) // would like to do something like this w/o adding parens
      .map(_.numBlah)
  }
```

I made up this nonce to check it out:

```
scala> List(1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49)
.map (_ * 2)
.map (_ / 2)
.map { case i if i % 2 == 0 => i / 2
       case i if i % 3 == 0 => i / 3
       case i => i * i }
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 8, 625, 18, 2401)
```

Lastly, the kind of computations you're constructing is best done with a for comprehension.

Comment: `map` isn't the right behavior. That's applying the match to all members of the list, when what I'm trying to do in some sense is assert that there is exactly one member of the list.

Comment: So try it. But you'll probably need to make some sort of predication of the “exactly one” criterion.

Comment: If you'd give an example that wasn't full of names defined only for you (and that gave inputs and desired outpus), I could at least try to give you exactly what you want. And if it was you who down-voted, I think that's a bit rude under these circumstances.

Comment: I did not downvote it. Sorry if the example was unclear.

Comment: Could you provide an example that involves known or defined types? I feel certain that what you want can be done.

Comment: E.g., we have a list of good Bar objects (List[Bar]) and we want a succinct way of converting to an Option[Bar] that is only defined if the list has exactly one element. Obviously this can be done in two statements, or using parentheses, but is there a succinct way of doing this in the middle of a chained pipeline of operations using only core libraries.